# How I can validate the syntax of if statement using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string input, and I want to check if this string contains the correct syntax of if statement. And extract every part of it.

String Format:

```
if(D1[Condition]D2)str1:str2
```

"**if**" should not be case sensitive
**D1** And **D2** should be numbers
**Condition** should be one of the following > < >= <= == !=

string examples:

```
$example   = "if(54>52)14:0";
$example   = "If(54==52)dsfd:fsde";
```

I used this regex but I'm not good at using regex and I don't know if it's good or not.

```
if\(\d+(==|<=|>=|>|<|!=)\d+\).+:.+
```

I want to extract D1 ,D2 ,Condition , str1 , str2

Comment: What about str1 and str2? Any requirements? Are these just alphanumerics? Or anything up to the `:`, then `:` and then anything up to the end of string?

Comment: just to be a string with maximum 50 characters

Comment: anything up to : ( maximum 50 characters )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
/^if\(\d+([<>=!]=|[<>])\d+\).{1,50}:.{1,50}$/i
```

This insensitively matches `if(`, then digits, then any or your operators, then digits, then `)`, then a string of maximum 50 characters, then `:`, then a string of maximum 50 characters.

Comment: @AhmedMansy it's a full php regex with the `i` modifier at the end making it insensitive.  As seen here:  https://regex101.com/r/yL3iJ8/1

Comment: I didn't know about the i 
Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
^if\((\d+)(>|<|>=|<=|==|!=)(\d+)\)(\w{1,50})\:(\w{1,50})
```

https://regex101.com/r/qZ7oM7/2

Comment: This doesn't properly cover the operators. For example `=>` would be accepted.  Also doesn't properly cover the 50 character maximum for the strings as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have it

```
/^If\s*\((\d+)\s*(==|<=|>=|>|<|\!=)\s*(\d+)\)\s*(\w{1,50})\:(\w{1,50})$/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/jR0bO1/1

I already added optional spaces in some places which you can add even more before and after other parenthesis. \w doesn't allow spaces in the strings. You can replace them with . to allow anything you want

Comment: @RedLaser I guess you forgot to refresh the page cause I pushed enter by mistake before finish writing that answer :)